# DOM function that creates an unordered list from an array

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I have tried creating a DOM function that creates an unordered list from an array. For example if you pass it the array ["hello", "food", "sun"], it will create the unordered list:

```
<ul>
<li>hello</li>
<li>food</li>
<li>sun</li>
</ul>
```

However, it creates nothing.
Here is the code for my DOM function:

```
<script>

function create_list(array,id){

var ul= document.createElement("ul")
ul.setAttribute("id",id)

//sets the id of the ul tag to the id specified as argument.

for (var i=0 ; i<array.length ; i++){

ul.appendChild.document.createElement("li").textContent= array[i]
//creates list elements inside of the ul tag.

}

document.body.appendChild(ul)

//adds the ul tag to the body of the html document.
}


//call the function
create_list(["hello","13","Kitchen"],13)

</script>
```

Why is it not working and how can I make it work?

Comment: `ul.appendChild.document.createElement` is simply wrong. Method chaining requires each method to return the initial object again - which `appendChild` doesn’t do, it returns the appended child. And even if that was different, `appendChild` still wants a _parameter_.

Comment: @CBroe: It would work if written properly. `ul.appendChild(document.createElement("li")).textContent= array[i]`. It merely missed the brackets.

Comment: @CBroe: You did not read the order of brackets correctly. You can literally copy past it into the console and convince yourself that it works. There you go: `var ul= document.createElement("ul"); ul.appendChild(document.createElement("li")).textContent='hello'; console.log(ul);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should seperate the logic of creating a child and appending a child.

you error comes from `ul.appendChild.document.createElement`..

I think it's better to use like below =)

```js
function create_list(array, id) {
  var ul = document.createElement("ul")
  ul.setAttribute("id", id)
  //sets the id of the ul tag to the id specified as argument.
  for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    var li = document.createElement("li");
    li.textContent = array[i]
    ul.appendChild(li);
    //creates list elements inside of the ul tag.
  }
  document.body.appendChild(ul)
  //adds the ul tag to the body of the html document.
}
//call the function
create_list(["hello", "13", "Kitchen"], 13)
```